# Connecting to an Azure Virtual Network from PC

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, vpn, azure-virtual-network

We have a Virtual Network of VMs, storage accounts and websites hosted and working together in the Azure cloud.

Is it possible to connect my work/home PC to this Virtual Network using some VPN software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking two options exist, you can read about these [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/networking/)  -

- [Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433122.aspx) let's you configure machine-to-machine VPN and is agent based
- [Configuring a private network](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/) let's you create a site-to-site VPN, but it typically [requires a VPN appliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx). I've seen posts on the internet about people managing to configure their router as the VPN gateway but, at least at this point, this is not easy nor supported.

Also worth reading is this [overview of Windows Azure Networking](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/networking/#Connect) features that covers both (and Traffic Manager) by David Chappel

Comment: `Windows Azure Connect` link is dead, can't google it either ;c [Windows Azure Connect retired on 7/3/2013 and is no longer operational](https://web.archive.org/web/20130928021040/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433122.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it can be done with [Point-to-Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) approach by using a client like [Azure VPN Client](https://install.appcenter.ms/users/user-microsoft/apps/azure-vpn-client-1/distribution_groups/publicgroup/releases/17) for azure AD account authentication.

I don't have the exact steps as it was set up by our devops guy in the end, but I know that it's possible at least.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at using Azure Virtual Networks in conjunction with Azure Virtual Machines: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/

Comment: I already have several VMs in a Virtual Network.  But now I want to connect my own computer into this Virtual Network.

Comment: the link i provided above contains another link to configure cross-premises connectivity between Azure and your own network.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build out a site-to-site VPN with a Windows Server. If you are able to obtain a copy of Windows Server 2016+, you can utilize RRAS to build the tunnel and port forward necessary ports to the server so the VPN Gateway (basic) in Azure can connect to the server via your home public IP address. Please ensure you obtain a legitimate copy of Windows Server before attempting this.

https://charbelnemnom.com/create-site-to-site-vpn-between-azure-and-windows-rras-server/#Introduction